# how to read each line in file and append to listView in android?

Tags: java, android, file, listview

First off I have two questions.

I am trying to create a simple highscore board in my game, when the user plays a game and finishes a dialog pops up and prompts for a name. From there I need to check if the file is already created, if not then create a file and write the name and score in. If file is already there then I need it to just add the name and score to the file not replace all of it.  But I have no idea what to use... Append'  or  'println' or 'write'.

Second I have a highscore screen, so if the user just wants to check the highscores (this is all on device) he goes into the screen and there I need the file to be read and each line should be put in an item inside a listView.

This is what I have for the file reading...

```
    try {
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStreamReader fr = new InputStreamReader(fi);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String test;
    while(true) {
        test = br.readLine();

            if (test == null)
                break;
            //textView.append("\n" + test);
            fr.close();
            fi.close();
            br.close();
    }
}  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}  catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: The problem of reading and writing files in Java has been addressed numerous times, so please check for yourself and ask concrete questions regarding coding problems instead of an incomplete code stub.

Comment: But my question for writing is what to use? Either Append, Write, or println. I've searched for other examples but without results that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want to use for something like this is a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Comment: I have that already but I don't know how to read each line in file and put as seperate items

Comment: You would .add() the line to the array that you pass into the adapter.

Comment: So where I commented in my code I should put something like... lv.add(et.getText().toString + " - "+ SCORE);

Comment: @user3055552 I'm not sure what "lv" and "et" are. If you have more than just a single string to show in each row, then you would want to extend ArrayAdapter and override the getView() method to implement a custom view for each row. You would probably also want create a new layout XML file for a single row (whose resource ID you would reference in constructing the custom ArrayAdapter).